# Do we need to close too specialized questions?

Tags: discussion

#### Do we need to close too specialized questions?

We have a bunch of questions that are very specialized for example we have 2 questions asking for academic references:

- [Need a reputable source for the formula for the shape of Earth's horizon](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/need-a-reputable-source-for-the-formula-for-the-shape-of-earths-horizon)
- [What exact algorithm and parameters reproduce L-system plant growth figure in Algorithmic Beauty of Plants](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/what-exact-algorithm-and-parameters-reproduce-l-system-plant-growth-figure-in-al)

Both basically ask us to go and find a resource for them to figure out the answer. Obviously that then means the answer would be of very poor quality.

Then we have a bunch of driver bug questions:

- [Code runs differently on different hardware](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/315/code-runs-differently-on-different-hardware)
- [How to make double working in OpenGL 4.1 on OS X ( Intel HD Graphics 5000 )?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/how-to-make-double-working-in-opengl-4-1-on-os-x-intel-hd-graphics-5000)

Obviously its very hard to answer these questions without owning a system with exact specs and version of driver.

There are other types, even one posted by me. Do we need to consider closing some of these question types?

Comment: "Obviously that then means the answer would be of very poor quality." Really? In principle pretty much *everything* that goes into an SE answer can be found somewhere on the internet or in a library. The main point of SE is to collect that knowledge. I think an answer that really pulls together the relevant information and presents it in a comprehensive way could actually be great content.

Comment: As for question relating to very specific hardware setups... you might have a point, but it can be hard to tell up front whether a problem is tied to the specific hardware or not. Also it would be great if we *could* provide content that helps people with hardware issues, but maybe we should try generating more content to help people solve hardware-specific problems on their own? Teaching a man to fish, and stuff...

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes but the point is things need to be answerable. If somebody says this works in X and not in Y then there isnt much we can do about it. Same applies to alot of unanswered questions

Comment: Very specialized questions can still become very interesting content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result